# Exchanging data between devices without an endpoint (no IP)

Tags: android, p2p, tcp, wifi-direct, data-transfer

I'm writing an Android app that works with sharing data between devices. I'm using both close transferring technologies (`Wi-Fi Direct`, `Bluetooth`) and Internet. I understand how `TCP/IP` works and so I would like to ask a question. **Is it possible to transfer data between two devices without a server** (peer-to-peer) **and without knowing the IP address of the host/receiver?**

What came to my mind is torrent clients, but as long as I'm correct they use torrent-servers to deliver the addresses to clients.

Though I have one more idea. Once I used a program (not sure it's the right name) `no-ip`. It gave me a `dns-adress` and I suppose it used its own server to redirect from the `DNS` to my `IP` which changed dynamically. Is it possible to try and make something like that on Android?

Comment: `Is it possible to transfer data between two devices without server (peer-to-peer)` No. And you need a client too.  `and without knowing the IP adress of the host/receiver?`. The client needs to know the ip of the server. Both client and server can send and receive. So dont talk about receiver like you did. Also you should not talk about host. I think you mean the server.

Comment: `I'm using both close (Wi-fi direct, Bluetooth) transering technologies and Internet. `. Close ??? You cannot compare internet with bluetooth or wifi direct talking about technologies.

Comment: @greenapps well first of all I've probably misused the word "close" as I meant close field communication which would be pretty easy to implement as I have worked with those. 
Besides, as you can understand I'm not very good in the topic so I'm sorry for misused terminology